# Conditional expectation is $L_p$ norm reducing

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

I am trying to follow the proof of
\begin{align*}
E \left(|E(X\mid \mathcal{B} )|^p \right) \le E(|X|^p)
\end{align*}
which goes as follows.
Let $f(t)=|t|^p$ which is convex for $p\ge 1$ then 
\begin{align*}
E \left(f(E(X\mid \mathcal{B} )) \right)  &\le E \left(E(f(X) |\mathcal{B} ) \right)  \text{ this is by Jensen's inequality}\\
&= E(f(X) ) \\
&=E(|X|^p)
\end{align*}
I don't undestand the second step where $E \left(E(f(X) \mid \mathcal{B} ) \right)=E(f(X) ) $. What happend  to $\mathcal{B}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the definition of conditional expectation, we know that for any random variable $Y$ $$E(E(Y|\mathcal{B})) = \int_{\Omega} E(Y|\mathcal{B}) dP = \int_{\Omega} Y dP = E(Y)$$ This is called the tower property of conditional expectation and intuitively it "gets rid of the $\mathcal{B}." $ Now just apply this to $Y=f(X)$.

Comment: Quick question. The above still works if we replace $\mathcal{B}$ with random variable $Z$, right?

Comment: Conditioning on a random variable $Z$ is just shorthand for using the sigma-field $\sigma(Z)$.

Comment: Yes, because $E(Y|Z):=E(Y|\sigma(Z))$ and this works for any sigma algebra.

Comment: Thanks got it. Another question if the inner expectation is taken with respect to measure $F$ and outer expectation is take with respect to $P$. Is this true: $E_P (E_F(Y|B))= \int E_F(Y|B) dP= \int Y dP =E_P(Y)$. Is this correct?

Comment: No, I don't think this is true. The subscript of the $E$ must match the measure with which you are integrating.

Comment: @Shalop Do you think it's an interesting question? Do you think it's worth asking it a separate question?

Comment: Sure. Go ahead.

Comment: I think that in general, we have that if $P$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $F$, then $E_P(E_F(Y|B)) = E_P(X \cdot \frac{dF}{dP})$, where $\frac{dF}{dP}$ is the radon-nikodym derivative.

Comment: I posted the question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203093/l-p-inequality-for-conditional-expectations-with-mismatched-distributions