# $L_p$ inequality for Conditional Expectations with Mismatched Distributions

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Suppose, we define $E_F[X]= \int X dF$ and $E_P[X] =\int X dP$.

We know that there exits the follow $L_p, \ p \ge 1$ inequality
\begin{align*}
E_P |E_P(X| \mathcal{B})|^p \le E_P[|X|^p]
\end{align*}
I was woundering if the following inequality holds:
\begin{align*}
E_P (|E_F(X| \mathcal{B})|^p) \le E_{???}(|X|^p) \text{ note the mismatch} 
\end{align*}
where $???$ is either $P$ or $F$?

We can still mimic a lot from the original proof. Let $f(t)=|t|^p$ which is convex for $p \ge 1$ therefore
\begin{align*}
E_P (f(E_F(X| \mathcal{B}))) \le E_P (E_F(f(X)| \mathcal{B}))
\end{align*}

But what to do next? I think maybe law of total expectation?

Comment: Maybe we should look at simple example like. Suppose we have $0$ means r.v. $X$ and $Z$ and $E_P[Z^2] < \infty$ and $E_F[X^2] < \infty$. Is it true that $E_P[(E_F[X|Z])^2] \le  E_P[E_F[X^2|Z]] \le E_F[X^2]$? The first inequality follows by Jensen's inequality. And I think the second one by law of total variance. Is that right?

Comment: The LHS depend on the version of $\mathbb E_F (X\mid\mathcal B )$ you consider. When $P$ and $F$ are singular, how do you define it?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I don't know much about singular distributions. Is there an issue if P and F are singular?

Comment: The random variable $\mathbb E_F( X\mid\mathcal B)$ is well-defined up the equality $F$-almost everywhere. But if a set $S$  is such that $F(S)=0$, there is no reason that $P(S)=0$. Hence the left hand side of your wanted inequality may be not well-defined in sense that it may take different values.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo wow. Very interesting. Would you mind giving an example. I will consider that as  an answer?